# Remove merge commits from pull request bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Assume there are 3 branches:

Develop
Feature-1
Feature-2

1. Feature-2 has a lot of commits.
2. I am on Feature-1.
3. I merge Feature-2 into Feature-1.
4. Feature-2 gets merged into Develop.
5. I continue committing to Feature-1.
6. I create Pull Request to merge Feature-1 into Develop.

Now, my Pull Request in Feature-1 will have all the commits from Feature-2, even though they have already been merged into Develop.

What can I do to remove these commits that are already in Develop?

Comment: next time rebase feature-1 branch against develop after feature 2 was merged. Then u can avoid such a situation

Comment: What if Feature-2 has not been merged into Develop yet?